# Django is init view twice

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Django is run in multithreading mode.
Main Thread and Django MainThread
How to run in a single-thread mode?
Also how to init view file once?

Comment: Please show the conf file of your http server

Answer (score 0):

By default, Django has been run in multithreading mode since  3.0 version. So I just disabled multithreading mode added --nothreading as server argument.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/django-admin/#cmdoption-runserver-nothreading
But this solution is useful for development mode.